# Is it possible to call a procedure inside a procedure, and if so, how? (Turing)

Tags: function, procedure, turing-lang

I've made a typewriter procedure for one of my programs in Turing, but I need it to be in a different font. I've tried Font.Draw, but since it's a procedure it wont let me use it inside the Typewriter Proc. Is there a way around this?

```
var chars : array char of boolean 
var font : int

font := Font.New("Pokemon GB:18")

proc TypewriterPrint(text : string) 
loop 
  for i : 1..length(text) 
  Input.KeyDown (chars) 
 if chars (KEY_ENTER) then 
    delay(50) 
    put text(i) .. 
 else
  delay(100) 
  put text(i) .. 
 end if 
 end for 
 put "" 
end loop 
end TypewriterPrint 

Font.Draw (TypewriterPrint("This will be printed like a typewriter"), 150, 150, font, black)
```

I've tried functions, but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You would call it the same way you call a regular procedure. Just create the first procedure outside of everything, create a second procedure outside of the first, and call the first procedure from within the second one.